# iOS Instagram public_content permission rejected

Tags: ios, api, instagram

I have a iOS app where I need public_content permission to search users and tags. My application allows user to create posts and add popular tags and users to caption.  here is screencast https://www.dropbox.com/s/k330dye9sbn6mz1/API%20use%20Mosaico%20public%20content.rtf?dl=0

**API Usage**

First API : **media/popular** = we are using this to get popular media. Based on that we are preparing a list of tags for "trending" (most used), to be used as auto suggestions in the caption edit mode.

Second API **users/search** = we are using this to create a list of auto suggest @ mentions in caption edit mode.

Third API : **tags/search** = we are using this to prepare a list (in alphabetical order), to auto suggest to the user based on a tag the they entered in caption edit mode.

**And reason Instagram gave is**

public_content:
This permission (public_content) is only granted to apps that enable brands, advertisers, broadcasters and publishers to discover public content. We do not grant access to apps that do not fall into these categories. Please review our documentation (https://www.instagram.com/developer/review) for more information.

Comment: Yeah, Instagram is tightening their grip on their APIs. You're app HAS to fall withing their allowed usecase, otherwise it will be declined.

Comment: There is no way to check what are their usecase, we made app for public and no login required , and it's for advertiser and publisher to find the most used / recent tags and right people and do post

Comment: Mukesh did you manage to get your public_scope granted?

Comment: No luck, not sure what they need

Comment: quick way to hack this if u only have basic permission is to save the access token of each user who connects to ur app